# Convert tuples into grouped rows in dataframe without changing the order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a tuple and I  need to convert it to dataframe.

```
res1_ =  [
  ('z1', '1'),
  ('z1', '2'),
  ('x1', '1'),
  ('x2', '1'),
  ('x1', '3'),
  ('z1', '1')]
```

My expected dataframe should be like this :

```
docid secid
z1    [1,2]
x1    [1]
x2    [1]
x1    [3]
z1    [1]
```

If you note, the order is not changed and if docid get repeated in next row, then two secids are merged into a single list.
Although x1 is occurring twice, sec id 1 and 3 are not in single list as we have docid x2 in mid of the x1s.

I tried with :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(res1_,columns=['docid','secid'])
df.groupby('docid')['secid'].apply(list)
```

But no luck as I am losing the order and x1 too is grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DataFrame constructor, then `GroupBy.agg`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(res1_, columns=['docid', 'setid'])
group = df['docid'].ne(df['docid'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df.groupby(group.values).agg({'docid': 'first', 'setid': list})
```

output:

```
  docid   setid
1    z1  [1, 2]
2    x1     [1]
3    x2     [1]
4    x1     [3]
5    z1     [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the data, and then convert to a dataframe:

```
from itertools import groupby 

grps = [(k, [t[1] for t in g]) for k, g in itertools.groupby(res1_, key=lambda x:x[0])]
df = pd.DataFrame(grps, columns=['docid', 'secid'])
```

Output:

```
  docid   secid
0    z1  [1, 2]
1    x1     [1]
2    x2     [1]
3    x1     [3]
4    z1     [1]
```